# como puedo juntar dos cadenas tipo string en una sola, pero que este salteado.(en java)

Tags: java, string

```
static void tar13() {
    String str="hello";
    String str1="abcde";
    String new_str=str.toUpperCase();
    String new_str1="";

    for(int i=0; i<new_str.length(); i++)
        //for(int j=0;j<str1.length(); j++)
            new_str1+=str.charAt(i)+str1.charAt(j); ??

    System.out.println(new_str1);
}
```

o sea si tengo: String str="hola"
                String str1="abcd"

yo quiero = HaObLcAd 
el único problema es cuando hago la nueva cadena que no se como hacer para que se sume cada vez un caracter distinto de cada cadena ...

Comment: Las dos strings siempre tienen el mismo largo? Si es así no es difícil, no necesitas dos bucles, porque siempre tienes que agregar las primeras letras de ambas strings, luego las segundas de ambas, luego las terceras, y así, se entiende?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías usar un StringBuilder para ir agregando los caracteres y al final formas el String:

```
public static String construirCadena(String cad1, String cad2) {
    int len = Math.max(cad1.length(), cad2.length());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(i < cad1.length())
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(cad1.charAt(i)));

        if(i < cad2.length())
            sb.append(cad2.charAt(i));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Llama a la función `construirCadena` con los 2 Strings que quieres combinar y te devolverá el String construido "salteado".